# Function pointers and callbacks in c/c++

Tags: c, function, pointers

I was trying to remind how pointers worked in c and c++ and I found this very interesting video ([Pointers in C/C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuegQmMdy8M&t=9408s)). In minute 3:14:00, he begins to talk about pointer functions and callbacks, and I ended a bit confused about the real application of them.

The example case he provides consists of a sorting algorithm that takes a function pointer as argument, which defines the comparison "rule" to follow (order from geater to smaller, order from smaller to greater, from greater to smaller given the absolute values...). He eventually ends with something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int compare(int a, int b){
    if(a > b) return -1;
    return 1;
}
void MyBubbleSort(int A[], int n, int (*compare)(int,int)){
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n-1; j++){
            if(compare(A[j], A[j+1]) > 0{
                temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j+1];
                A[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int i, A[] = {3,2,1,5,6,4};
    MyBubbleSort(A,6,compare);
    for(i=0; i<6; i++) printf("%d ",A[i]);
}
```

When he wants to change the comparison rule, he changes the compare(int, int) content and that's all. My question is, why would he do that, instead of just having a separate function called compare(int, int) that just does the same as the one showed in the code snippet, and just call that function from within MyBubbleSort(int[], int). Wouldn't it just have the same behaviour? What are the benefits then? Are there any other interesting use cases?

Thank you very much for answers!

Comment: What's being demonstrated is that one `BubleSort` function can be written that exhibit multiple behaviors.  `BubbleSort` could sort ascending, then descending, then odds-before-evens, then primes-before-non-primes, without writing four different-but-mostly-identical functions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking why he passes a function pointer to `MyBubbleSort` instead of just having it hardcoded to call `compare()`?  (It's made more confusing by the fact that the function itself, and the parameter of function pointer type, are both named `compare`.)  That's so that in a larger program, you could have several different comparison functions and still only have to write `MyBubbleSort` once.

Comment: Because now you can use `MyBubbleSort` to sort in ascending order, in descending order or in any other order you want without changing it. You just pass a different function to it. It may not seem good yet - you could just copy and paste `MyBubbleSort` to another function, right? But the concept of reusability is crucial for any professional programmer. Take a look at [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) library - every function allows you to change its behaviour by simply passing another function to be executed inside.

Comment: @Javier "When he wants to change the comparison rule, he changes the compare(int, int) content and that's all. My question is, why would he do that, instead of just having a separate function called compare(int, int) that" - Your question does not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Because they used the same name for function and parameter. The question is "Why pass a function pointer if you could just call the function by name?". The tutorial failed to provide an example of passing another function there I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you, right after reading your replies I figured out that my question was quite naïve as just thinking about it for a minute would have let me understand its goal. What confused me was the fact that he changed the pointer function rather than creating a different one, and therefore I thought that having a non pointer function would have the same result. Sorry and thank you all very much again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the main point is something that he mentions in the narration but does not include in the sample code: you could have several different comparison functions in your program, and use them at different times as appropriate, while still having just one `MyBubbleSort` function.

An example might look like:

```
int compare_increasing(int a, int b){
    if(a > b) return -1;
    return 1;
}

int compare_decreasing(int a, int b){
    if(a < b) return -1;
    return 1;
}

void MyBubbleSort(int A[], int n, int (*compare)(int,int));


}
int main(){
    // ...

    // sort in increasing order
    MyBubbleSort(A,6,compare_increasing);

    // sort in decreasing order
    MyBubbleSort(A,6,compare_decreasing);
}
```

Comment: That's it, now I see it very clearly. Sorry for the "nonsense" question, I should have gave it a few more minutes to figured that out. However, thank you very much!

Comment: @Javier: I agree with you that the way the sample code was written,  it definitely obscured that point.

Answer (score 1):

1. Calling a function by a pointer in this case makes the sorting function universal.
2. If you hardcode the comparison in that function it will work only for that condition.
3. C does not have lambda expressions and anonymous functions so the compare function has to be written separately and the pointer passed.